# scalafx animation upon layout change

Tags: animation, layout, javafx, scalafx

I'm trying to animate changes in layout in a ScalaFX application, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828234/animation-upon-layout-changes). The scene includes one main Pane. Each time it is clicked, another Pane ("son") is added inside it (actually inside a FlowPane inside it). Pane addition should "push up" previous sons and, if needed, "squeeze" the previous sons (up to their minimum height).

There are two problems:

1. the animation is not smooth. Sometimes, when a son is added or the window is resized, there is a flicker ("glitch") in which the position and/or the scale of the nodes become momentarily incorrect. I tried setting initial value as suggested in the quoted answer but it did not seem to solve it.
2. when resizing the window by dragging the bottom edge the movement animation starts correctly from the current location. However, when dragging the top edge, there is a jump is the initial location.

code follows:

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.animation.{ScaleTransition, TranslateTransition}
import scalafx.geometry.Pos
import scalafx.scene.control.ScrollPane
import scalafx.scene.layout._
import scalafx.util.Duration

object Main extends JFXApp {
  stage = new PrimaryStage { scene = new Scene (new NodePane, 800, 600) }
}

class NodePane(isExternal: Boolean = true) extends BorderPane  {
  def makeMargin = new FlowPane {
    prefHeight = 30
    minHeight = 10
  }

  top = makeMargin
  center = if (isExternal) new SonsPane() else new EmptySonsPane()
  bottom = makeMargin
}

class SonsPane extends ScrollPane {
  val vbox = new VBox {
    fitToHeight = true
    fitToWidth = true
    alignment = Pos.Center
  }
  content = vbox

  onMouseClicked = (e: MouseEvent) => vbox.content.add(makeSonPane())

  def makeSonPane() = {
    new NodePane(isExternal = false) {
      prefHeight = 150
      // initial initialization
//      scaleY = 0.1
      var prevPos = layoutY.value
      var prevHeight = height.value
      // change events
      layoutY.onChange {
        if (prevPos != 0) {
          val translation = new TranslateTransition(Duration(600), this) {
            fromY = prevPos - layoutY.value
            toY = 0
          }
          translateY = layoutY.value - prevPos
          translation.play()
        }
        prevPos = layoutY.value
      }
      height.onChange {
        val scaling = new ScaleTransition(Duration(600), this) {
          fromY = prevHeight / height.value
          toY = 1
        }
        scaleY = prevHeight / height.value
        scaling.play()
        prevHeight = height.value
      }
    }
  }
}

class EmptySonsPane extends FlowPane {
  style = "-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: yellow; -fx-background-opacity: 0.5"
  minHeight = 100
}
```

Comment: I have found a much simpler solution: adding the new son and animating its pref height from 0 to pref height. This solution achieves the same scaling and positioning effects when a son is added but not when the window is resized (ok for me)