# Animating Layouts JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I just want to find out if there is any simple way of animating layouts in JavaFx, such as the VBox and HBox. I would like my application to change the background color of my VBox after a specified time. But I realized that there is nothing similar to FillTransition that I could use to do this using a VBox or an HBox. Any advice on how I could do this?

Comment: See: [Animation upon layout changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828234/animation-upon-layout-changes)

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is not related to layout at all. You just want to transition the background color, right?

Comment: Maybe. You could create a custom event which is fired whenever you want to change all styles. So you could e.g. listen to it in custom vbox or hbox by using some kind of interface and do the style animation? Haven't tried that but...:)

Answer (score 0):

Color transition is very easy with the [2.0-SNAPSHOT version of ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX#snapshot-releases):

```
ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.WHITE);
Val<Background> animBgr = Val.animate(color, Duration.ofMillis(500))
        .map(c -> new Background(new BackgroundFill(c, null, null)));
vbox.backgroundProperty().bind(animBgr);
```

Now whenever you update `color`, the background color of `vbox` will smoothly transition to the new color in 500 milliseconds.

If you want to change color every 5 seconds, you can create an *EventStream* of colors that *emits* a color every 5 seconds and use that color to set the value of `color`:

```
private static final Color[] COLORS = new Color[] {
    Color.WHITE, Color.AQUA, Color.web("#FFDA8F"), Color.CORAL, Color.CYAN
};

private EventStream<Color> colorStream() {
    return EventStreams.ticks(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .accumulate(0, (n, t) -> (n + 1) % COLORS.length)
            .map(i -> COLORS[i]);
}

colorStream().feedTo(color);
```

A full runnable demo looks like this:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.reactfx.EventStream;
import org.reactfx.EventStreams;
import org.reactfx.value.Val;


public class ChangingBackgroundColor extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final Color[] COLORS = new Color[] {
        Color.WHITE, Color.AQUA, Color.web("#FFDA8F"), Color.CORAL, Color.CYAN
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();

        ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(COLORS[0]);
        Val<Background> animBgr = Val.animate(color, Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .map(c -> new Background(new BackgroundFill(c, null, null)));
        vbox.backgroundProperty().bind(animBgr);

        colorStream().feedTo(color);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox, 400, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    private EventStream<Color> colorStream() {
        return EventStreams.ticks(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .accumulate(0, (n, t) -> (n + 1) % COLORS.length)
                .map(i -> COLORS[i]);
    }
}
```

**Stopping the animation.** If the VBox is removed from the scene before the application exits, the animation should be stopped in order to prevent memory and CPU leaks. The `feedTo` method above returns a `Subcription`, which I ignored in the sample code above. In order to stop the animation, you would do:

```
Subscription subscription = colorStream().feedTo(color);

// later
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Firstly I'd like to thank you for the insight. I have mutiple background images that I'm switching when a button is pressed. But I would like to automate it instead. i.e mainVbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFDA8F;"); I would like to change to each color automatically. Once I have been through all the colors, I'd like it to go back to the first color and continue till program termination

Comment: @Explorer24 So again, what do you mean by "automatically"? You don't want to have to press the button, but rather change the color after a certain period? Also, do you have background _images_ (like JPEGs) or just background _colors_?

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the background after lets say 5 seconds. I'm just changing the bakground colors. No images. Want I want is more like what you said earlier, update color and smoothly transition to the new color in the specified time.

Comment: If you could I would appreciate an example of code where you show how to do this using either a VBox or an HBox.

Comment: Does ReactFx allow you to use CSS colors?

Comment: @Explorer24 What do you mean by CSS colors? If you just want to specify the color as "#FFDA8F", the `Color` class from JavaFX already supports that: `Color.web("#FFDA8F")`. ReactFX itself does not know anything about CSS.

Comment: @Explorer24 I updated the code to use one color specified like this.

Comment: I keep getting an error in eclipse on the Val.animate. It says:  The method animate(ObjectProperty<Color>, Duration) is undefined for the type Val. Any help?

Comment: @Explorer24 Are you sure you are using the latest _snapshot_ version of ReactFX?

Comment: I'm currently using reactfx-2.0-M3

Comment: @Explorer24 A convenience method was added that is currently only available in the snapshot version (will be in 2.0-M4). With 2.0-M3, you can do `Val.animate(color, Duration.ofMillis(500), (a, b, x) -> a.interpolate(b, x))`, i.e. specifying the _interpolator_ explicitly.